# ksoap 2 input parameters being null

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I have a web service which has following operation

```
public String loginVerify(String email, String password){


}
```

and I am consuming this service on android using ksoap2 library. This is code

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "loginVerify");
    PropertyInfo emailProperty=new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo passwordProperty=new PropertyInfo();
    emailProperty.setName("email");
    emailProperty.setValue(emailText);
    passwordProperty.setName("password");
    passwordProperty.setValue(passwordText);
    passwordProperty.setType(String.class);
    emailProperty.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(emailProperty);
    request.addProperty(passwordProperty);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);         
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try 
    {           
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        String dumprequest=androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
        String dumpresponse=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        String result = response.toString();
```

I am getting null pointer exception as error and after debugging I came to know that the input parameters `(email, password)` are null. Where is the problem.

Comment: Do emailText and passwordText contain anything before making request? Where do you set them?

Comment: @Melquiades yes they contain the correct parameters.

Comment: Do you catch this null on the server side?

Comment: @piobab yes I debugged and found out that email and password are null on server side and everything else works fine. I even tried to use SOAPUI and everything works fine in SOAPUI.

Comment: Atlast found out the issue
I have to change `email and password to arg0 and arg1` as in WSDL the input parameters are specified by these names.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you should add your authentication data to header. Check my response. If it does not help let me know so i will post the whole procedure which I used for communication with web service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your authentication data to header:

```
envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();
```

and method:

```
private Element buildAuthHeader() {
    Element h = new Element().createElement(SERVICE_NAMESPACE, "MyHeader");
    Element username = new Element().createElement(SERVICE_NAMESPACE, "email");
    username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "your_email");
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);
    Element pass = new Element().createElement(SERVICE_NAMESPACE, "password");
    pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "your_password");
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);
    return h;
  }
```

Comment: thanks buddy but commented above what was the problem and the solution